# AWS lambda not opening window using node.js

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, lambda

I have simple requirement wherein i need to open a window with given URL using node.js, which is deployed on AWS as Lambda function.
Following is the sample code I am trying, the execution of lambda function returns as Success, but no window is opened in any browser, i.e. the url is not launched. When I execute the same code on windows or linux, I can see a window getting launched.

```
function summaryHandler (event, context, callback) {
  console.log('Will open google page');
  var open = require('open');
  open('http://www.google.com');
  callback(null, 'Your window should be launched by now');
}
exports.summaryHandler = summaryHandler;
```

Can you please tell me where is the issue?

Answer (score 4):

If you try to do this in Lambda, it would try to open the said webpage on the AWS server, not on your local machine. You could instead try to return a redirect to the webpage.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/redirection-in-a-serverless-api-with-aws-lambda-and-amazon-api-gateway/